Law of the land of oppressors
Historically it turns out we used to struggle under the oppression of the nations. Did the "dina demalkhuto dina" apply to the oppressors as well? Should have communist laws in the USSR been followed? What about a Jew that finds themselves in Iran? Must the law of the country be observed for peace or for religious reasons because it was accepted as a nation to keep the laws of the host country?
What about having only One King, only one Torah a and no other King but Hashem? I've read dina dmalkhuto was as accepting the harsh force of the current governing power as the sole reason or so.
Where does the law of the land is the law apply?

I think this has been asked before?

This question is similar to: Limits to Financial Dina Dmalchusa. The answer there answers this, even if the question itself is somewhat different. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See this answer also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/144152/31534

"No king but God" sounds like a great idea and is a wonderful theological goal, but as Pirkei Avos says: "if not for the fear of government, people would swallow each other alive." As I stated in the other answer: there is a very clear pragmatic understanding that flawed government is still vastly preferable to anarchy.
